# Trimming String up to a Specific Character in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a vector of Strings in R that represent NCAA Basketball Player's names.
The names are displayed as below:

```
(Justin Ahrens\justin-ahrens-1 
Kyle Ahrens\kyle-ahrens-1 
...
Zavier Simpson\zavier-simpson-1)
```

How can I trim these names so I get "Justin Ahrens" and "Zavier Simpson" rather than what I have now?

Comment: Do you have vector of strings or one single string? If it is a vector then why do you have `()`  only for first and last element?. It is better to add data in reproducible format which we can copy preferably using `dput` to avoid the confusion. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that different rows in your example correspond to different elements in the vector of strings. Then you can apply the following:

```
string_vector <- c("(Justin Ahrens\\justin-ahrens-1",
                   "Kyle Ahrens\\kyle-ahrens-1", 
                   "Zavier Simpson\\zavier-simpson-1)")

gsub("\\(|\\)|\\\\.+$", "", string_vector)
```

Here, you are getting rid of any parenthesis `\\(|\\)` or any string that comes after backslash, including the backslash `\\\\.+$`

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your names are presented in the data, so I will offer a couple of possible solutions using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

## Case 1: names are vectorised
players1<- c("Justin Ahrens\\justin-ahrens-1",
                   "Kyle Ahrens\\kyle-ahrens-1", 
                   "Zavier Simpson\\zavier-simpson-1")
# Use str_extract
players1 %>% str_extract("[^\\\\]+")

## Case 2: one long character string containing multiple names and newlines
players2 <- ("(Justin Ahrens\\justin-ahrens-1\nKyle Ahrens\\kyle-ahrens-1\nZavier Simpson\\zavier-simpson-1)")

# Split strings on new lines (alternatively "1" if no newline characters), then map str_extract

players2 %>% str_split("\n") %>%  
purrr::map(~str_extract(.x,"[^(\\\\]+")) %>% 
unlist
```